# Symfony 5: Auth Multiple Guards and Different Providers

Tags: symfony5, symfony-security

I am struggling with Symfony's guard authentication system for an API, it seems impossible to get it to work how I need.

Is it possible to use multiple authenticators AND different providers?

I need the flexibility so that users can potentially be authenticated in two ways for the same endpoints.

My firewall is currently:

```
        api:
          pattern: ^/
          stateless: true
          provider: jwt
          guard:
              authenticators:
                  - App\Security\InviteCodeAuthenticator
                  - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
              entry_point: App\Security\InviteCodeAuthenticator
```

The JWT and invite code need totally different user providers.  If I create a different firewall for each, then I have the same URLs protected by different firewalls and I need it to use either.

I am pulling hair out trying to get this to work now, I feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Note, I have tried the chained providers here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/multiple_user_providers.html which isn't really ideal but even then still fails as soon as the first provider fails to find a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who may encounter this, I had to use Symfony's new experimental authentication system to get this working:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html#authenticators-removed-anonymous

Then using a hybrid firewall:

```
        api:
          pattern: ^/
          stateless: true
          provider: jwt
          entry_point: App\Security\InviteCodeAuthenticator
          custom_authenticators:
                  - App\Security\InviteCodeAuthenticator
          guard:
            authenticators:
                  - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

This allowed my invite code authenitcator to inspect the request for a valid invite code and allow authentication or failign that fall back to expect a JWT.